# Libre Office Macro to crop image

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org, uno, libreoffice-basic, openoffice-basic

I have a Libre Office Macro and I need to crop an image, but I have been unable to find any helpful documentation or an example.  Anyone have a tip how to do it?

```
dim noArgs()
dim emptyDocComponent as object
dim document as object
dim dispatcher as object
emptyDocComponent = StarDesktop.LoadComponentFromUrl("private:factory/swriter", "_blank", 0, noArgs())
frame = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

dim args1(3) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args1(0).Name = "FileName"
args1(0).Value = "file://" & inputPath
args1(1).Name = "FilterName"
args1(1).Value = "<All formats>"
args1(2).Name = "AsLink"
args1(2).Value = false
args1(3).Name = "Style"
args1(3).Value = "Graphics"

dispatcher.executeDispatch(frame, ".uno:InsertGraphic", "", 0, args1())

selection = ThisComponent.CurrentSelection
If selection.ImplementationName <> "SwXTextGraphicObject" Then
   Exit Sub
End If

' this is what the macro recorder captured, but it was "rem" and non-functional
rem dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:Crop", "", 0, Array())
```

*** edit

Here is what I am now using in case it helps someone else.  I had a picture with a known size in pixels that needed to be cropped.  Not entirely sure the calculation is completely accurate, but it is working so far.

```
dim noArgs()
dim emptyDocComponent as object
dim document as object
dim dispatcher as object
emptyDocComponent = StarDesktop.LoadComponentFromUrl("private:factory/swriter", "_blank", 0, noArgs())
frame = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

dim args1(3) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args1(0).Name = "FileName"
args1(0).Value = "file://" & inputPath
args1(1).Name = "FilterName"
args1(1).Value = "<All formats>"
args1(2).Name = "AsLink"
args1(2).Value = false
args1(3).Name = "Style"
args1(3).Value = "Graphics"

dispatcher.executeDispatch(frame, ".uno:InsertGraphic", "", 0, args1())

selection = ThisComponent.CurrentSelection
If selection.ImplementationName <> "SwXTextGraphicObject" Then
   Exit Sub
End If

' size = (pixels / pixelsPerInch) * mm/in * scaling * actual graphic / displayed graphic
imageWidth = (int(pixelWidth) / int(xPixelsPerInch)) * 25.4 * 110 * (selection.actualSize.Width / selection.Width)
imageHeight = (int(pixelHeight) / int(yPixelsPerInch)) * 25.4 * 110 * (selection.actualSize.Height / selection.Height)

GraphicCrop = selection.GraphicCrop
GraphicCrop.Top = selection.actualSize.Height - imageHeight
GraphicCrop.Bottom = 0
GraphicCrop.Left = 0
GraphicCrop.Right = selection.actualSize.Width - imageWidth
selection.GraphicCrop = GraphicCrop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextGraphicObject has a struct called [GraphicCrop](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/TextGraphicObject.html#GraphicCrop).

The following code was adapted from https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=72496.

```vb
selection = ThisComponent.CurrentSelection
If selection.ImplementationName <> "SwXTextGraphicObject" Then
   Exit Sub
End If

pxPerInch = 100*25.6
cropFig = selection.GraphicCrop
cropFig.Left = 0.27*pxPerInch
cropFig.Right = 1.34*pxPerInch
cropFig.Top = 0.31*pxPerInch
cropFig.Bottom = 0.18*pxPerInch
selection.GraphicCrop = cropFig
```

Comment: this is what I used.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Search the net for "DannyB" (in combination with `OpenOffice`) to find his very useful libraries on StarBasic macros for the `Draw`component.

I'm pretty sure he has an example.

Other resource to look into: Andrew Pitonyak's "OpenOffice Macros Explained", might have an example as well.

Comment: I searched for DannyB's libraries and found https://sourceforge.net/projects/ooomacros/files/Danny_s%20Draw%20Power%20Tools/ and https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Danny%27s_Python_Modules, but did not find anything for cropping.  Nor was Andrew's document helpful in this case.  Perhaps you could provide a specific link.

Comment: No, Jim. If I could have I would have done it.  Last time I read DannyB's examples was about 10 years ago in oooforum.org and don't remember any specific